# Issue in building Image in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild

I'm building image through the below command by using AWS code build and getting errors.

Commands:

```
docker buildx build -t "$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG" --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --push .
```

Error:

```
[Container] 2022/08/01 09:49:38 Running command docker buildx build -t "$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG" --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --push .
unknown shorthand flag: 't' in -t
```

also while im removing "-t" it's throwing

```
[Container] 2022/08/01 09:26:44 Running command docker buildx build $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --push .
```

> unknown flag: --platform See 'docker --help'.

Can anyone help here with how it will be resolved?